# join two select statements side by side Sql

Tags: sql, join

I have two select query statements. I dont know to create table here.

Below are two tables. Id is same, but Fname and Lname is different.

Table1 have two columns

```
 id Fname 
 1  Ahila
```

Table2 have two columns

```
 id Lname 
  1 Kavitha
```

Output table should be single row with id and Fname and Lname : 1 and Ahila and Kavitha respectively

Please help me on this.

Comment: What about just use `join` SQL statement?

Comment: Yes i did. But the output comes like two rows. like union

Comment: What exactly query you've tried? Usage of join in situation you've described can't produce two rows. Add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a join to join the two tables together, something like:

```
select t1.id, t1.Fname, t2.Lname
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN statement

```
SELECT T1.id id , T1.Fname Fname, T2.Lname Lname 
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
select Fname 
from Table1 
join Table2
on Table1.id = Table2.id
where id = 1
```